# jQuery Mouseover targetting all Divs in Wordpress Blog template

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I have a Wordpress Blog template
The image is floated to right and the text (title, date, category, summary) is floated left.
I want to change the text background color and Text-color when hovering mouse on image, but when i hover mouse on it, the jQuery targetting all posts in blog page. I want it to target only a single post, how to do it?

Here is the PHP

```
<h1 class="thumb" style="z-index:2; width:252px;">
                    <a class="odkaz" style="padding:15px 15px 5px 15px; width:252px; heighty:109px;font-size:30px; font-weight:100; " href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', UT_THEME_NAME ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                </h1>

               <br/>

                <div class="post-ut" style="margin-top:-43px;"> 
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php the_time('d. m. Y, g:i') ?> | <?php lambda_posted_in(); ?>                            
                </div> <!-- post by -->

            </header>

        <?php 

            echo '<div class="thumb" style="width:282px; padding-left:282px; margin-top:-114px; margin-bottom:20px; "><div class="post-image"><div class="overflow-hidden imagepost">';
            echo '<img class="wp-post-image"  style="display:inline-block; width:282px; height:272px;" src="'.$url.'" />';
            echo '<a title="'.get_the_title().'" href="'.get_permalink().'"><div class="hover-overlay"><span class="circle-hover"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/circle-hover.png" alt="'.__('link icon',UT_THEME_INITIAL).'" /></span></div></a>';
            echo '</div></div></div>';

        endif; ?>

        <div class="entry-content clearfix">

        <div class="entry-summary">

            <?php if ( is_archive() || is_search() || get_option_tree('excerpt_blog') == 'yes') : 

                the_excerpt(); 

            else : 
         ?>



           <?php endif; ?>   

        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->

        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Here is the jQuery

```
$('.thumb').mouseover(function() {
$('.thumb a').css("color","black");
$('.thumb a').css("background","#ff7f00");
$('.post-ut').css("color","black");
$('.post-ut a').css("color","black");
$('.post-ut').css("background","#ff7f00");
$('.entry-summary p').css("color","black");
$('.entry-summary p').css("background","#ff7f00");
```

});

```
$('.thumb').mouseout(function() {
    $('.post-ut').css("color","white");
    $('.post-ut a').css("color","white");
    $('.post-ut').css("background","black");
    $('.thumb a').css("color","white");
    $('.thumb a').css("background","black");
    $('.entry-summary p').css("color","white");
    $('.entry-summary p').css("background","black");
});
```

Comment: Hi. It'd be helpful if you could post the markup after it has been parsed, rather than posting the php

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using the `this` as a second parameter for elements inside .thumb element. For others, if they all have a common parent, you can use this.parent() like follows:

```
$('div.thumb').mouseover(function() {
    $('a', this)
       .css("color","black")
       .css("background","#ff7f00");
    $('.post-ut', $(this).parent())
       .css("color","black")
       .css("background","#ff7f00")
       .find('a').css("color","black");
    $('.entry-summary p', $(this).parent())
       .css("color","black")
       .css("background","#ff7f00");
}
```

The second parameter of the jQuery selector `$` limits the query to the elements inside that element. `this` here refer to the element that was mouseover-ed (.thumb) in this case.

Comment: The selector should be `div.thumb`. Also, you can't call `.parent()` on `this`, it has to be wrapped in a jQuery object: `$(this).parent()`. One more thing, it's inefficient to keep selecting the same elements, you should chain the methods

Comment: Definitely. These are great notes. Updated the code accordingly. Just was trying to keep the changes to minimal not to alienate the original user who posted the question with too much changes.

Comment: +1, the selector still needs to be `div.thumb` (notice OP has a `h1` with the `.thumb` class as well)

Comment: @mkhatib Thanks your code worked, Now each single post is changing div not all of the posts. But the "a" is not working  -->         $('a', this)
       .css("color","black")
       .css("background","#ff7f00");

Comment: Resolved Updating the code of first line "a" to $(this).parent()) resolves the issue Thank you both for helping me

Comment: Another question, As image is floating to right, i added padding 50% to left, I want this padding space  and all elements on it to hoverable (changing colors of text on hover), how can i make it hoverable?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. As for the padding. Can you explain why you want to do this and maybe a link to your blog would help, but generally padding space should be hover-able (at least in CSS, not sure about the mouseenter event though.)